# Maven expression resolving issue

Tags: java, expression, maven-3

how do I make maven to interpret only inner expressions in files ? Concrete situation is :

within archetype I'm creating, there is a resource web.xml element :

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>webAppRootKey</param-name>
    <param-value>${artifactId}.root</param-value>  //${artifactId} gets resolved
</context-param>
```

and in log4j.properties there is this line

```
log4j.appender.logfile.File=${${artifactId}.root}\WEB-INF\resources\${${artifactId}.root}.log
```

where the inner expression should be interpreted by maven but the outer one not, because that is for log4j. Does maven recognize that it should resolve only the inner one ? or it doesn't see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>I've never tried this with maven, but can you do something like this instead?</s>

```
<properties>
    <log.root>${artificatId}.root</log.root>
</properties>
```

You'll want to have a look at `escapeString` from the [maven-resources plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/resources-mojo.html#escapeString).

Comment: I don't understand how it should help, I could do it like this instead logfile.File=${artifactId}.root ... The point is, that there must be logfile.File=${myapp.root} after resolution so that log4j can resolve it itself

Comment: @lisak: I am sorry, I misinterpreted your question. Have a look here: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/resources-mojo.html#escapeString